# How to implement the "robot legs" use case with Google Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm learning Google Guice. Do you know how to implement the "robot legs" problem? Let me explain this with an example.

Let's say that I have some class called `Service`:

```
@Singleton
public class Service {
    @Inject
    Source source;

}
```

The interface `Source` has two implementations:

```
public class SourceDatabase implements Source {

}

public class SourceFileSystem implements Source {

}
```

My module is implemented like this:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Service.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

Well, I would like to know if this is possible:

```
public class MainClass {    

    @Inject @SomeAnnotation("database")
    Service serviceWithADatabaseSource;

    @Inject @SomeAnnotation("file-system")
    Service serviceWithAFileSystemSource;

}
```

Does exist some annotation or binding that let me do that, let me annotate a member like `serviceWithADatabaseSource`, and this helps Guice to know that the internal member `source` should be injected with the `SourceDatabase` implementation?

**Edit:** Thanks to Daniel Martin, for give us the name of this kind of problem on his comment.

Comment: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects  (What you've described is the "robot legs" problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [documented in the Guice Wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects), you need to install two [PrivateModule](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html)s, each of which exposes a Service with the right annotation for you.

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    install(new PrivateModule() {
      @Override public void configure() {
        // Bind Source to SourceDatabase.
        bind(Source.class).to(SourceDatabase.class);
        // Bind @Named("database") Service to Service.
        bind(Service.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("database"))
            .to(Service.class);
        // Now expose @Named("database") Service without exposing
        // either of the other two conflicting bindings.
        expose(Service.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("database"));
      }
    });
    install(new PrivateModule() {
      @Override public void configure() {
        // Same as above.
        bind(Source.class).to(SourceFileSystem.class);
        bind(Service.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("file-system"))
            .to(Service.class);
        expose(Service.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("file-system"));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If the modules were not PrivateModule instances, those bindings to Source and Service would conflict with one another. However, instead, each binding inherits all the public bindings from the Injector but only exposes the `@Named(...) Service` to the outside world. This way the same `Service` implementation can inject the same non-annotated `Source` but have it return different fully-injected types.

Also note that you will not be able to ask for a `Source` or `Service` (without an annotation) outside of the PrivateModules, because you haven't established a binding in any non-private Module. This should be expected: The PrivateModule bindings shouldn't conflict with any public bindings, and without entering through one of the PrivateModule's exposed bindings, Guice won't know which `Source` or `Service` to return.

Finally, given that Module instances can take constructor parameters, it may be a good idea to extract the two anonymous inner PrivateModules into a named equivalent:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    install(new SourcePrivateModule(SourceDatabase.class, "database"));
    install(new SourcePrivateModule(SourceFileSystem.class, "file-system"));
  }
}
```