# Inject different instance for reusable component with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, implementation

I am new do dependency injection and I'm trying to solve the following problem with Google Guice:

In a web application I have got tabs which need to be reused multiple times but each time with different dependencies on their UI component and model. Something like the code here:

```
class MenuTabView
{
   private MenuTab fooTab;
   private MenuTab barTab;
}

class MenuTab
{
   private UiComponent component;

   @Inject
   public MenuTab(UiComponent component)
   {
      this.component = component;
   }
}

class UiComponent
{
   private Model model;

   @Inject
   public UiComponent(Model model)
   {
      this.model = model;
   }
}

class FooComponent extends UIComponent {}
class BarComponent extends UIComponent {}

class FooModel implements Model {}
class BarModel implements Model {}
```

How can I inject FooModel and FooComponent into fooTab
and BarModel and BarCompoment into barTab?

I've read a lot about the different techniques available in Google Guice but none of them seams to fit this problem which, to my naive eyes, should be a simple one. I've tried to give fooTab and barTab binding annotations but they will only work if I inject the tab but not the dependencies of the tab. What would be the most convenient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate? [How to implement the "robot legs" use case with Google Guice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784112/how-to-implement-the-robot-legs-use-case-with-google-guice)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the common "robot legs" problem to me ... this is covered in the [FAQ](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) and can be solved by using private modules:

```
class LegModule extends PrivateModule {
  private final Class<? extends Annotation> annotation;

  LegModule(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
    this.annotation = annotation;
  }

  @Override 
  protected void configure() {
    bind(Leg.class).annotatedWith(annotation).to(Leg.class);
    expose(Leg.class).annotatedWith(annotation);

    bindFoot();
  }

  abstract void bindFoot();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
    new LegModule(Left.class) {
      @Override void bindFoot() {
        bind(Foot.class).toInstance(new Foot("leftie"));
      }
    },
    new LegModule(Right.class) {
      @Override void bindFoot() {
        bind(Foot.class).toInstance(new Foot("righty"));
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution and I think it is the right one for the problem I presented so I'm upvoting it! Unfortunately this method brings me to a dead-end in my case where I have to create the instance of the UI component (new Foot(...) in the example). The Foot constructor is annotated with @Inject and has got another 5 dependencies in our case which I cannot resolve at this point, can I?

Comment: Check if provides methods could be a solution (instead of "bindFoot"): https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods