# Configure Guice to contain 2 services of the same type with different implementations of their dependencies

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I would like to ask how to configure Guice, so the resulting DI container will contain 2 instances of the same class, but each one supplied with different implementation of their dependencies.

Consider there classes:

```
interface Foo {}
class FooImpl1 implements Foo {}
class FooImpl2 implements Foo {}
class Bar(Foo foo) {}
```

Suppose you could do dependency configuration using some YAML(ish)

```
services:
    - 
        name: "Bar-1"
        type: Bar
        dependencies:
            - FooImpl1
    - 
        name: "Bar-2"
        type: Bar
        dependencies:
            - FooImpl2
```

Notice that there **is instantiation logic** in YAML configuration, stating that for instance of `Bar` named `Bar-1` (we need to somehow name our instances to be able to distinguish between them, as they have the same type) will be supplied with `FooImpl1`, and instance named `Bar-2` with `FooImpl2`.

How could I achieve this using a Guice configuration? I explicitly stress that I don't want to modify the code classes in any way.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement the "robot legs" use case with Google Guice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784112/how-to-implement-the-robot-legs-use-case-with-google-guice) (this is the classical robot-leg issue which is answered here on Stack Overflow and in [Guice's wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects)),