# Google Guice binding using Annotation and Key class

Tags: binding, annotations, guice

Lets say we have **A.java** interface implemented by **AImpl.java** and **B.java** implemented by **Bimpl.java**

Above classes are binded in two modules as below

```
Module1 {
    bind(A.class).to(AImpl.class);
    bind(B.class).to(BImpl.class);
}

Module2 {
    Key<A> aKey = Key.get(A.class, AnAnnot.class);
    bind(aKey).to(AImpl.class);
    Key<B> bKey = Key.get(B.class, AnAnnot.class);
    bind(bKey).to(BImpl.class);
}


Class AImpl implements A {
}

Class BImpl implements B {

@Inject
BImpl(A aImpl) {
 //??
}
}
```

BImpl refers to A

For BImpl binded using Annotation, I want corresponding aImpl, binded using Annotation but here I'm getting aImpl which is not binded using Annotation

Please suggest

Comment: By the way, aren't you using the same implementation for both with annotation and without annotation?

Comment: That's right. I'm trying to find a way to align wiring; classes binded with Annotation and without annotation.

Comment: Then what is the problem, are you getting the same instance for both cases? I am a little lost :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement the "robot legs" use case with Google Guice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784112/how-to-implement-the-robot-legs-use-case-with-google-guice)

Comment: @Olivier -  Thanks for trying to help but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. May be I didn't phrased my question well. Please see below solution I used, may not be the best but it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to achieve using below pattern. May be there is a more easier way. Happy to know more

> A.java

```
public interface A {
    String aMethod();
}
```

> AImpl.java

```
public class AImpl implements A {

    private String moduleName;

    public AImpl(String moduleName) {
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
    }

    @Override
    public String aMethod() {
        return moduleName;
    }
}
```

> B.java

```
public interface B {
    String bMethod();
}
```

> Bimpl.java

```
public class BImpl implements B {
    private final A a;

    BImpl(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public String bMethod() {
        return a.aMethod();
    }
}
```

> AnAnnot.java

```
@Target(PARAMETER)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface AnAnnot {
}
```

> BProvider.java

```
public class BProvider  implements Provider<B> {
    private final A a;

    @Inject
    BProvider(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public B get() {
        return new BImpl(a);
    }
}
```

> BHavingAnnotatedA.java

```
public class BHavingAnnotatedA implements Provider<B> {
    private final A a;

    @Inject
    BHavingAnnotatedA(@AnAnnot A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public B get() {
        return new BImpl(a);
    }
}
```

> ABModule1.java

```
public class ABModule1 extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(A.class).to(AImpl.class);
        bind(B.class).toProvider(BProvider.class);
    }
}
```

> ABModule2.java

```
public class ABModule2 extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        Key<A> aKey = Key.get(A.class, AnAnnot.class);
        bind(aKey).to(AImpl.class);
        Key<B> bKey = Key.get(B.class, AnAnnot.class);
        bind(bKey).toProvider(BHavingAnnotatedA.class);
    }
}
```