# Guice how to bind one class with different paramaters?

Tags: java, bind, guice

I want to create two instances with one class by injecting different parameter. For example:

```
class Foo {
  private String config;
}
```

I want two `Foo` instances, one's config is `A`, another one is `B`, how should I do?

Comment: Guice sometimes calls this the ["robot legs problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35784112/1426891), imagining a common Leg with a LeftFoot and RightFoot instead of a Foo with a config A and config B. Is that similar enough to mark as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to achieve what you are after. without a little more information of your use case its hard to say the better of the ways.

For this answer i'll limit the scope to provide you with an example of a provider type solution.

first fully defined your class

```
    private class Foo {
    private String config;

    public Foo(final String config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

In your GuiceModule.java create 2 different providers

```
@Provides
@Named("foo1")
public Foo provideFoo1() {
    return new Foo("value1");
}

@Provides
@Named("foo2")
public Foo provideFoo2() {
    return new Foo("value2");
}
```

and then these objects can be injected into a single object (like below) or multiple different objects

```
private class ManagerManager {
@Inject
public ManagerManager(
        @Named("foo1") final Foo config,
        @Named("foo2") final Foo config2) {}
}
```

if injecting one of them into multiple objects, you may wish to have a singleton concept for both Foo1 and Foo2, so add @Singleton onto the provider

if you have a use case that the value (for foo1/foo2) is not known until runtime, then its better to ask for an example of an assistedFactory